# Organic Internet Simple Configurable Products - Special Price

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm using the Organic Internet Simple Configurable products extension for a store which I've edited to change more content when a user selects an option from the configurable product.

When using "Special Prices" if the special price is NOT the cheapest price then it won't show the "Original Price"

For example, I have a product with 4 options which are prices from £32 up to £49.
My product with a special price is £49 with a special price of £45 - If I change this to have a special price of £31 (or anything lower than £32) then it shows the "Original Price" crossed out, but if the special is over £32 then the "Original Price" doesn't show.

Has anyone used this extension before and perhaps has had the same issue?

Comment: This extension just causes a lot of problems. Not the developer's fault - it's just really hard to cover all the behaviors.

Comment: Yeah, it's a good extension but it has it flaws. I've modified it a lot to cover stuff like Related products, up-sell and some other bits! It's weird that it seems to work on some products but not where the Special is lower than the cheapest product available!